# Changing the colour of a pushbutton using python/raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm working on a project for work which is essentially a remote monitor that looks at the status of drawbridges. I have a GUI set up that i designed with PyQtDesigner with 8 buttons that are currently coloured red and want them to go green when drawbridges come down. I'm using the GPIO on a raspberry pi to get a signal from the drawbridges but cant get the buttons to change to green.

```
    self.pushButton_7.setStyleSheet("background-color: red")
```

that's how the buttons are coloured initially but unsure how to change them to green with an input from the raspberry pi, any pointers will be super helpful!
(totally new to pi's and python!)